# Assigning a value to a nested xml when using the SOAP npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, npm

I have been able to successfully invoke a web service call using in the soap npm library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap)

What I want is to be able to assign values as I have been doing and then call the web service but I think that this will not work as there are repeating XML structures and how do I map my value i.e. `<adl:stops>` - There could be more than one stop so how does soap npm handle this.

The documentation does not seem to tell me how to create a JSON structure that will allow me to assign values for the web service call.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using node.js to create a call

My code is :

```
var url = 'https://preprod.blackcab.ro/external-ws/adler/wsdl';
    var args = {
      login: 'xxxxxxx',
      password: 'xxxxxxxx'
    };

    var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      console.log('....start');
      soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('..error', err);
          throw new Error(err);
        } else {

          client.Login(args, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('> error = ', err);
              reject();
            } else {
              console.log('>result = ', result);
              resolve(result);
            }

          });
        }
      });
    }); // promise

    return p;
```

The service is defined as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:adl="http://www.haulmont.com/sherlock/adler">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <adl:LoginRequest>
         <adl:login>?</adl:login>
         <adl:password>?</adl:password>
      </adl:LoginRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

That was quite easy... now I am having difficulties calling a nested xml function defintion i.e.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:adl="http://www.haulmont.com/sherlock/adler">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <adl:QuotationRequest>
         <adl:sessionId>?</adl:sessionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <adl:retailSessionId>?</adl:retailSessionId>
         <adl:job>
            <adl:accountNumber>?</adl:accountNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:pin>?</adl:pin>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:caller>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:individualId>?</adl:individualId>
               <adl:name>?</adl:name>
            </adl:caller>
            <adl:asap>?</adl:asap>
            <adl:serviceCode>?</adl:serviceCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:jobDate>?</adl:jobDate>
            <adl:paymentType>?</adl:paymentType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:numberOfPassengers>?</adl:numberOfPassengers>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:deadline>?</adl:deadline>
            <adl:routeInfo>
               <adl:destinationUnknown>?</adl:destinationUnknown>
               <adl:waitAndReturn>?</adl:waitAndReturn>
               <adl:asDirected>?</adl:asDirected>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:asDirectedHours>?</adl:asDirectedHours>
            </adl:routeInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:promoCode>?</adl:promoCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <adl:creditCard>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:id>?</adl:id>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:startDate>?</adl:startDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:expiryDate>?</adl:expiryDate>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:holderName>?</adl:holderName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:number>?</adl:number>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:cvcNumber>?</adl:cvcNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:issueNumber>?</adl:issueNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:billingAddress>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:country>?</adl:country>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:street>?</adl:street>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:streetNumber>?</adl:streetNumber>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:town>?</adl:town>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:postcode>?</adl:postcode>
               </adl:billingAddress>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:encryptedDetails>?</adl:encryptedDetails>
            </adl:creditCard>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <adl:actors>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:individualId>?</adl:individualId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:name>?</adl:name>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:telephone>?</adl:telephone>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:email>?</adl:email>
               <adl:type>?</adl:type>
            </adl:actors>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <adl:references>
               <adl:entityName>?</adl:entityName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:value>?</adl:value>
            </adl:references>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <adl:specialInstructions>
               <adl:typeCode>?</adl:typeCode>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:value>?</adl:value>
            </adl:specialInstructions>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <adl:stops>
               <adl:operationType>?</adl:operationType>
               <adl:address>
                  <adl:formattedAddress>?</adl:formattedAddress>
                  <adl:latitude>?</adl:latitude>
                  <adl:longitude>?</adl:longitude>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field0>?</adl:field0>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field1>?</adl:field1>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field2>?</adl:field2>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field3>?</adl:field3>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field4>?</adl:field4>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field5>?</adl:field5>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field6>?</adl:field6>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field7>?</adl:field7>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field8>?</adl:field8>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field9>?</adl:field9>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field10>?</adl:field10>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:field11>?</adl:field11>
               </adl:address>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:contact>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:individualId>?</adl:individualId>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:name>?</adl:name>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:telephone>?</adl:telephone>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:email>?</adl:email>
               </adl:contact>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:airportDetails>
                  <adl:airportCode>?</adl:airportCode>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:terminalCode>?</adl:terminalCode>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:flightNumber>?</adl:flightNumber>
                  <adl:eta>?</adl:eta>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:pickupTimeDelay>?</adl:pickupTimeDelay>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:airline>?</adl:airline>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:arrivalFrom>?</adl:arrivalFrom>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:meetingPoint>?</adl:meetingPoint>
               </adl:airportDetails>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:trainDetails>
                  <adl:trainStation>?</adl:trainStation>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:meetingPoint>?</adl:meetingPoint>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:pickupTimeDelay>?</adl:pickupTimeDelay>
                  <adl:eta>?</adl:eta>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:arrivalFrom>?</adl:arrivalFrom>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <adl:trainNumber>?</adl:trainNumber>
               </adl:trainDetails>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <adl:notes>?</adl:notes>
            </adl:stops>
         </adl:job>
      </adl:QuotationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I think that you may want to checkout xml2js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js. Works well with node-soap.